# Why won't my input conform to the height of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a form, but I'm having some serious issues...

My `input` heights are set to 100%, and their parent is set to 30px, however, the height of the input in practice are more than 30px... so I set `padding` and `margin` to `0`... still nothing.

Code:

```css
body{
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input{
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
.label13{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.label24{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
}

.form-element{
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="formValidation.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <div id="wrapper">
     
         <div class="form-element">

          <label class="label13" for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e.g. yourname@gmail.com">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label24" for="phone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="e.g. 778-333-3215">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label13" for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label24" for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm">
        </div> 
   </div>
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
       
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I've added some color to make it easier to understand.

What you see is that the first three *seem* to conform to the right height, but they don't, it only appears that way because they're are vertically aligned to the top; if I set the height to 200%, you can see the text go far lower than the viewable input itself and eventually disappear.

What is causing this? I want the inputs to be the same height as the labels.

Comment: you have default border

Comment: Your inputs have additional 2px for their top and bottom borders. 
Solution- make it borderless or adjust height of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your css.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Otherwise, your input height is actually 100% + 2px for the border top and bottom. By using `box-sizing: border-box;`, you are telling it to instead include the border in the calculated height, so it never gets higher than 100%.

```css
body{
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input{
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
.label13{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.label24{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
}

.form-element{
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="formValidation.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <div id="wrapper">
     
         <div class="form-element">

          <label class="label13" for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e.g. yourname@gmail.com">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label24" for="phone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="e.g. 778-333-3215">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label13" for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

       <div class="form-element">
          <label class="label24" for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm">
        </div> 
   </div>
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
       
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```